# How do I set a Restriction in Hibernate to target a column in either one of two joined tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm joining one table to another. The join works. I want to restrict the results to records with an "Error" message that can be in either table. When I do the following, I get no results back, yet I know there should be 2.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TableName.class);
criteria.createAlias("someList", "things");

Criterion restriction1 = Restrictions.eq("status", "Error");
Criterion restriction2 = Restrictions.eq("things.anotherStatus", "Error");
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(restriction1, restriction2));

finalList = criteria.list();
```

I noticed that the restrictions *by themselves* actually work. So, if I only do the first restriction on the original table with no alias OR if I only do the second restriction on the alias table, then I get 1 result each time.

Also, a simple join SQL query like the one below works as expected:

```
Select count(*) 
From table1 t1
Left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.another_id
Where t1.status = 'ERROR' or t2.anotherStatus = 'ERROR'
```

How can I get this right in Hibernate?

**EDIT 1:** I now see that Hibernate does an Inner Join when I use the `@JoinColumn` annotation. How can I change it to do an Outer Join instead?

**EDIT 2:** Even adding [@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/FetchMode.html) still results in an inner join! What gives? The documentation clearly says it will do an outer join. The annotation now looks like this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="ID_FK")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private List<Thing> things;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** use `criteria.createAlias("someList", "things", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);` instead.

**Explanation:** When no `JoinType` is specified, `createAlias` does an `inner join` by default.